# Open url in new IE window and not maximized?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

We have a Windows Form that needs to open a browser window with a specific url. I use something like this to open the browser:

```
Process.Start("IExplore.exe", "http://example.com");
```

It works great since it opens a new browser window instead of just a tab. The issue now is that the browser window always opens in maximized form, so the app is not displayed anymore.

Is it possible to open IE so that it doesn't show as being maximized? That way, the user can see both the browser and the app.

Thanks.

Comment: try setting the startInfo.WindowStyle - but it could be it looks full screen its just defaulting to the size of the screen

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use something like:

```
void OpenWithStartInfo()
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

    startInfo.Arguments = "www.northwindtraders.com";

    Process.Start(startInfo);
}
```

For more info, you can check [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle.aspx)

Comment: I had tried that, The problem is that the browser opens minimized, so the browser is not being displayed. It also opens two instances of IE.

Comment: You might wanna remove one of the "Process.Start" line of code. As MSDN repeated it there for demo purposes!

Answer (score -1):

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("IExplore.exe");
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

If that isn't what you are looking for...

Try reading this link from Microsoft. It allows you to resize a process's window size - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633545.aspx

Comment: I had tried that, The problem is that the browser opens minimized, so the browser is not being displayed.

Comment: @rbhatup I think that should help you.

Comment: @rbhatup Did this second link help? Are is that still not what you are looking for?

Comment: Not relevant, not helpful. Dumping a link with no explanation doesn't make a good answer, *even if it were the right answer*. This is not.